# How would I create a new instance of the database in Meteor.js when a new a unique url is passed in?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am building a "magnetic poetry game" with Meteor.js, which I am very new to.

Here is what I have so far:

http://test-magnets.meteor.com/

I am using the homepage as a group play board, where all users can collaborate and build poems together.  That is working fine but I want to build an option that you can create your own private board to play by yourself.

I used iron:router to create an unique url which is the userId.  I would like to create a new instance of the collection that does not affect the group board.  Right now every time you move a piece in the group board, it changes the database in the userId url.  Is there a simple way to implement this or is this pretty complicated?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Your separate page should subscribe just to the object it's dealing with, check this tutorial http://meteortips.com/tutorial/publish-subscribe-autopublish/

Comment: Hey @user3557327: consider http://tinyurl.com/so-username please?